# How to call a Singleton's Destructor When Closing Console Application?

Tags: c#, singleton

I am a little confused if my current application is doing what I require. I want to basically just create a Singleton and when the Console application is terminated, call the Destructor of the Singleton. I have it so the Console App will terminate when I hit ENTER, but I am not exactly sure if this is doing what I want. When I put a breakpoint in the Destructor, it gets hit ONLY when I do hit Enter. I just want to make sure what I am doing is correct and if not, how can I change it.

Here is my Singleton:

```
 public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> lazy = new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());
    public static Singleton Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }
    private Singleton() { }
    ~Singleton()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Destructor Called."); // Breakpoint here
    }
}
```

And in my Main:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Singleton instance = Singleton.Instance;
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

EDIT: Got it working, thanks!

Comment: The finalizer (i.e. destructor) is for the GC to call; `Dispose` is for the developer to call.

Comment: singletons rarely need deconstructed. consider using a single instance of something that implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: along with what @KennethK. said. finalizers are never guaranteed to run and shouldn't access anything outside of the class - things might be in an inconsistent state.

Comment: Isn't implementing IDisposable on a Singleton bad practice?

Comment: @DanielA.White, neither must the finalizers access anything (*managed*) **in** the class instance itself. Best practice for using finalizers: **don't use finalizers**.

Comment: @Cuphead, please provide us more details. What exactly do you want to do in the destructor/finalizer/`Dispose`/whatever? And **why** do you need it?

Comment: I don't want to do anything right now with the Destructor. I just want to see it actually get hit / fired off when I close the Console Application. @dymanoid

Answer (score 2):

You can't call destructor programmatically. It is always called by .NET CLR in garbage collection. However for your singleton, I would strongly discourage use of destructor.

Recommendation is to [implement IDisposable interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern),  if you want to release any resources. **Or any custom interface implementation will work as well to release any resources, because its weird to implement IDisposable on Singleton**.

```
public sealed class Singleton : IDisposable
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> lazy = new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());
    public static Singleton Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }
    private Singleton() { }
    ~Singleton()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Destructor Called."); // Breakpoint here
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dispose Called.");
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Singleton.Instance.ToString();
        ((IDisposable)Singleton.Instance).Dispose();
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```